# Force Required to Lift a WEIGHT of 1Kg

Tags: motors, torque

I want to lift a mass of 1kg so how much force is required ?

Comment: "W [weight] =mg = 1kg" That is just wrong. If $m = 1$  kg and $g = 9.81$, m/s then $W$ (weight) = $1 \times 9.81 = 9.81$ **Newtons**. "United States customary units" are totally confusing - so don't try to understand them until you have got your thinking straightened out in SI units - and don't confuse yourself even more with hybrid monstrosities like "kilograms force".

Comment: which of the 5 clear and simple answers on the yahoo answers page don't you understand?

Comment: I'll echo alephzero's comment to reinforce this - start with SI units and the dimensions they represent.  Then (re)introduce the combinations of those units to derive other properties such as force, acceleration, etc... Once you're truly comfortable with the units and their combinations, then start considering values applied to the units.  And stay away from Imperial units / US customary units for as long as possible.

Comment: @alephzero how about "poundal" ... ? :)

Comment: your question is down voted because it is utter nonsense. Frankly I'm a little concerned someone might come across the question and try to make sense of it.  ( It seems there are not enough folks with close vote privledges on this site )

Comment: @agentp - there's plenty of folk with close vote privileges, but we certainly need more.  And we need more exercising that privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mass is measured in kg and weight measured in N.

Comment: Mass - measure quantity of matter, while Weight is a force due to gravitation. A kilogram of mass can have zero force, or 9.81N force depends on gravity (but still, it is 1 kg quantity of mass).